# To check singularity of given function

Tags: complex-analysis

At $z=0$ the function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^{z}+1}{e^{z}-1}$ has

(a) a removable singularity

(b) a pole

(c) an essential singularity

(d) the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is $2$.

This question has more than one answer.

My try: by considering Maclaurin series for $e^{z}$ after simplification we get
$$f(z)=\frac{2}{z+\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\cdots}+1$$
So one thing is clear that $f(z)$ has no essential singularity or removable singularity. Is this a right approach? What about explanation for option (b) and (d)?

Comment: I suggest you use a partial fraction decomposition on the fraction you have above. Basically the setup is: $\frac{2}{z(1 + \frac{z}{2!} + \frac{z^2}{3!} + \dots)} = \frac{A}{z} + \frac{B_0 + B_1z + B_2z^2 + \dots}{1 + \frac{z}{2!} + \frac{z^2}{3!} + \dots}$. The main interest here is the value of $A$ since the second fraction is well defined for $z = 0$. With this I believe you will arrive at seeing that this is a pole with a residue of 2 at $z = 0$.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Anything more need to be said?

Comment: Earth to Kns, come in please.

Answer (score 3):

If you can prove that $\lim_{z\to0}zf(z)$ exists and equals the nonzero number $c$, then you will have proved that $f$ has a (simple) pole at $z=0$, with residue $c$.